# Entity Group - deciding on how to group

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've read throughout the Internet that the Datastore has a limit of 1 write per second for an Entity Group. Most of what I read indicate a "write to an entity", which I would understand as an update. Does the 1 write per second also apply to adding entities into the group?

A simple case would be a Thread where multiple posts can be added by different users. The way I see it, it's logical to have the Thread be the ancestor of the Posts. Thus, forming a wide entity group. If the answer to my question above is yes, a "trending" thread would be devastated by the write limit.

That said, would it make sense to get rid of the ancestry altogether or should I switch to the user as the ancestor? What I'd like to avoid is having the user be confused when they don't see the post due to eventual consistency.

Comment: Have you read this: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/

Comment: Great read. It explains the concepts to consider very well. However, as with other articles, the example used regarding write limits was for updates of entities.

Comment: What's "logical" isn't always the right answer with Datastore. You need to think about the queries and updates that your application needs.  If you need strong consistency, then, yes, having Thread as a Post's ancestor might make sense.  But do you need strong consistency?  If not, don't use an ancestor and you'll not suffer the same write contention.

Comment: worth pointing is that you can get strong consistency without ancestors, by doing "get by key" queries

Answer (score 1):

## **A quick clarification to start with**

1 write per second doesn't mean 1 entity per second. You can batch writes together, up to a maximum of 500 entities (transactions also have a 10 MiB limit). So if you can patch posts, you can improve your write rate.

Note: you can technically go higher than 1 per second, although your risk of contention errors increases the longer you exceed that limit as well as the eventual consistency of the system.

You can read more on the [limits here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits).

## Client-side sharding

If you need to use ancestor queries for strong consistency AND 1 write per second is not enough, you could implement client-side sharding. This essentially means that you write the posts to a up to `N` different entity-groups using a known key scheme, For example:

- Primary parent: "AncestorA"
- Optional shard 1: "AncestorA-1"
- Optional shard N: "AncestorA-(N-1)"

To query for your posts, issue `N` ancestor queries. Naturally, you'll need to merge these results on the client-side to display it in the correct order.

This will allow you to do `N` writes per second.